# How to calculate a range from two subranges and a full range?

Tags: calculus

I'm designing a screen calibration process and I'm facing this mathematical issue from secondary education that I'm not being able to solve.

To make it easier, I'm going to talk about X axis only (screen width).

I have a screen which width goes from $[0,800]$ pixels (this is the full output range).

For the calibration process, I paint some marks near the corners (the top-left corner in coordinates is $(0,0)$ and top-right$(800,0)$) at $(20,y)$ and $(780,y)$ (y is height and is not relevant for this), in other words, a subrange from $[20,780]$ (width, output subrange).

Finally, when the user clicks at the marks, the coordinates I get from the program (it get's from the operative system, and can vary a lot from one to other) in this case is $[144.25,875.75]$ (input subrange).

In the past, this process was done clicking directly in the corners ( $(0,0)$ and $(800,0)$ and therefore, I know that the coordinates that operative system returns for the corners are 125 at the left and 895 at right==> full input range: $[125,895]$

The thing is, having this the two subranges (**output: $[20,780]$ and input $[144.25,875.75]$) and the full range output($[0,800]$) how do I get to know the input full range ($[125,895]$) (in this case I know it, but what happens if I change the operative system? I would know the two subranges and the full output range but I wouldn't know the full input range).

I know this formula to remapping between ranges:

$$\frac{(\text{value} - \text{from $1$})}{\text{to $1$} - \text{from $1$}} \times (\text{to $2$} - \text{from $2$}) + \text{from $2$}$$

But it doesn't apply here.

Does anyone have a hint? Thanks in advance

Comment: I would love to help but the text is hard to follow. You should formulate this in a more mathematical way. What even are "the corners" (which first are $(20, 20)$ and $(780,20)$ and then magically are something like "[125 to 895]")? A picture would be useful, too.

Comment: Hi! Sorry for my writting.
The screen "corners" are the maximum and minimum where my touch screen detects input (in pixels, (0,0) would be top-left corner (800,0) top-right (im not indicating height to simplify the problem)).

Comment: I remade a bit the question, hope it clarifies the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have two scales, one in your program that goes from $0$ to $800$.  Let us use $z$ for a variable that works in that range.  The second is the range the operating system uses, which goes from $a$ to $b$ and you are assuming that the relationship between the two is linear.  We will use $x$ for a variable in OS coordinates.  From the clicks you get $x(20)$ and $x(780)$.  The total range tells us that $b-a=\frac {800}{760}(x(780)-x(20))$.  The center gives us $b+a=x(780)+x(20)$  We can solve those to get
$$b=\frac12\left(\frac{1560}{760}x(760)-\frac{40}{760}x(20)\right)\\
a=\frac12\left(\frac{1560}{760}x(20)-\frac{40}{760}x(760)\right)$$
and now
$$x=a+\frac z{800}(b-a)\\z=800\frac{x-a}{b-a}$$

Comment: Very good and detailed answer. As I want to keep my code as clean as possible, I had use your solution in another way. 
If my marks are in the 1/4 and 3/4 of total width, I can easily obtain the center from user input. Once I have the center, I can get the values I want substracting or adding with Mark2 - Center (that is a 1/4 of the screen).
Thansk a lot for your answer.